# Junit method not found

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to build a sample test class using junit framework.
I've downloaded junit4.9b3.
When I try to complie my test class I get the following error:-

```
javac -cp ".;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\junit\junit4.9b3\junit-4.9b3.jar"     
TestSubscription.java    
TestSubscription.java:10: cannot find symbol    
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)    
location: class TestSubscription    
            assertTrue(s.pricePerMonth()==100.0);        
            ^
TestSubscription.java:17: cannot find symbol    
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)    
location: class TestSubscription    
            assertTrue(s.pricePerMonth()==66.67);
            ^
2 errors
```

Looks like assertTrue is not available but the junit javadoc mentions this method.
I'm using the import as follows

```
import org.junit.*;     
import org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You've imported the types, but not used a [*static* import](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to make the members available without qualification. If you use:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

then that should statically import all the static methods in the `Assert` class, so you can write `assertTrue` instead of `Assert.assertTrue`.

Note that presumably `Assert` itself has nested types, otherwise I'd have expected your "normal" import to fail.

Answer (score 10):

You have to do a static import.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```